# modify value of map with forEach

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a HashMap and want to change the value (which is a string) by appending another string "hello".

```
HashMap<User, String> all = new HashMap<>();
mymap.forEach((k, v) -> v = v + " hello");
```

However, it does not work, "mymap" is unchanged. What is wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the job for [`Map#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
mymap.replaceAll((k, v) -> v + " hello");
```

Comment: Does this replace the whole map? such as mymap.putAll (which replaces also duplicate keys?)

Comment: It will apply the `BiFunction` to each entry in the map and replace the value with the result